# Stopping IO.popen in the middle of execution using Exceptions given a bad condition

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby script, I call on a Perl script and wait for it to finish executing.   However, there are times that the Perl script encounters a series of errors and I would like Ruby to be able to handle these errors automatically.  So, I implemented the following...

```
begin
    IO.popen(cmdLineExecution) do |stream|
          stream.each do |line|
              puts line
              if line =~ /Some line that I know is an error/
                 raise MyOwnException
              end 
          end
    end

    begin
          #Wait on the child process
          Process.waitpid 
    rescue Errno::ECHILD
    end
rescue MyOwnException
   #Abort the command mid processing, and handle the error
end
```

However, the Perl script continues to execute even though an exception has been thrown, only that it is not piping the output to `STDOUT` anymore.  At this point, if I want to stop the Perl process, I have to go into the Task Manager and manually stop it.  Then `Process.waitpid` ends and continues from there.  It is either that or I stop Ruby and the Perl process continues to run in the background and I still have to manually stop it.

BTW: This is on Windows

So thus the question is how do I stop IO.popen without the Perl process from becoming a orphan process mid process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So - disclaimer, I am using Ruby 1.8.6 and on Windows.  It is the only Ruby that the software I use currently supports, so there may be a more elegant solution.  Overall, it came down to making sure the process died using the Process.kill command before continuing execution.

```
IO.popen(cmdLineExecution) do |stream|
  stream.each do |line|                         
      puts line
      begin
        #if it finds an error, throws an exception
        analyzeLine(line) 
      rescue correctionException 
        #if it was able to handle the error 
        puts "Handled the exception successfully"
        Process.kill("KILL", stream.pid) #stop the system process
      rescue correctionFailedException => failedEx
        #not able to handle the error
        puts "Failed handling the exception"
        Process.kill("KILL", stream.pid) #stop the system process
        raise "Was unable to make a known correction to the running enviorment: #{failedEx.message}"
      end
  end
end
```

I made both the exceptions standard classes that inherit `Exception`.